# How to get response.id as string from Facebook Login Java SDK

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, authentication, sdk

I stuck in the following process:

Here is the well known "Facebook Login for the Web with the JavaScript SDK example":
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

I want to get the Facebook USERID as a simple string to pass it to a PHP variable. Altough the USERID is shown when I print the $fbID, but it's not a string.

How can I get the USERID as a simple string (or a number)...?

Here is my code:

```
  <?php
  $fbID = "<script>
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = response.id;
    });
  }
</script>";
?>
</script>
<div id="status">
</div>

<?php
echo $fbID;

$sql = "select id from customer where fbid = '$fbID' and status = '1'";
  $table = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
list($realid) = mysqli_fetch_array($table,MYSQLI_BOTH);
echo $realid;
?>
```

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to persist the ID in your database. Add the following code to your `FB.api('/me', function(response) { }` function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'persistID.php',
    type: "POST",
    dataType:'json', 
    data: ({id: response.id}),
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

And create a seperate persistID.php file where you persist the FacebookID:

```
<?php

    $ID = $_POST['id'];

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (fbid) VALUES ($ID)";

    // Persist userid
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for the information!

Is it possible to use the result of the ajax query on the same php file? 
E.q. I want to use the whole code on my login.php. 
After I have the $.ajax data, I just want to echo it on that page as a php variable $ID = $_POST['id'];

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Also, do not output html and javascript with `echo` in php. I personally consider this to be bad practice. It looks terrible in text editors with syntax highlighting, you have to worry about escaped strings... Do your stuff with plain html and javascript, and use separate php files. Access them with ajax calls.

Comment: Oh I get it! I don't want to echo this on my page in the end, I know, this is useless :) I just want to test it, because with my previous code I was already able to echo the response.id, altough I can't use the variable because it wasn't a string. I already have one fbid in a same row with an existing customer on my MySQL DB, and my aim is to pass the response.id to a PHP variable, than use this to request the ID of the affected user from MySQL who have this fbid.